# Select 2 different columns from 2 different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I'm trying to select 2 different columns (`newsID` from the table `news` and `movID` from the table `movies`) so that I can use `mysql_num_rows` to grab the items in those conditions.

I tried this with the code below, but it is not working. How can I fix it?

```
$queryy="SELECT newsID FROM ".PREFIX."news WHERE published='1'";
$queryy="UNION (SELECT movID FROM ".PREFIX."movies WHERE activated='2')";
$all=safe_query($queryy);

$gesamt=mysql_num_rows($all);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overwriting the variable with the second assignment. Do it all in one string assignment:

```
$queryy = "SELECT newsID FROM ".PREFIX."news WHERE published='1'
           UNION (SELECT movID FROM ".PREFIX."movies WHERE activated='2')";
```